# Can I use 2 different power supplies to power the electret mic and op amp separately?

Tags: power-supply, operational-amplifier, audio, grounding, ground-loop

[image]
the power supply is a placeholder and it will be rated 12v to power the ne5532 op amp since 5v cannot power the op amp. The 5v dc will come from the same usb as the sound card which the electret mic will be connected.

I want to do this in order to prevent ground loops by powering the components separately.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on what you want to achieve.

There are a few problems. The mic is connected to op-amp with only one path, so it won't work. Mic gnd reference needs to be connected to op-amp gnd to have a common reference.

Also 5V from USB is noisy. And since you have a larger supply for op-amp, you can use that for mic too, with filtera and dividers to bring it down to 5V.

Comment: I want to make a mic preamp for recording on my pc. I am worried that a ground loop may occur due to the power supply being connected separately from the computer.

Answer (score 1):

Your 1k resistor powering the mic has such a low resistance that it shorts the mic signal.
Use a 1k resistor then a 47uF to ground for a filtered 11.6V supply to a 12k resistor powering for the electret mic. Then the mic signal will have much less noise and have much higher level. The mic will have about 6.8V across it producing less distortion.

Your two parallel 470uF capacitors are ridiculous and will pass earthquake frequencies and take 44 seconds to charge.

Comment: Oh that was a mistake in my part, it's supposed to be nf. Thank you

Comment: Do the math. Two paralleled 470nF capacitors in parallel pass earthquake frequencies down to 3.6Hz into the 47k opamp input resistor. One 0.1uf (100nf or 104) passes audio down to 34Hz.